# Microsoft Graph: Can I (re)use the user's Bearer Token forwarded by AAD in order to make "delegated" calls to the Graph API?

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api

I have developed SharePoint (online) SPFx Webpart (using TypeScript/JavaScript) that calls the Azure Function. Upon calling the Azure Function, the AzureAD forwarded some headers, such as:

```
..
authorization: "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ii1LSTNRO.........",
..
..
x-ms-client-principal: "eyJhdXRoX3R5cCI6ImFhZCIsImNsYWltcyI6W3sidHlwIjoiYXVkI..........",
x-ms-client-principal-id: "588301bd-048a-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX",
x-ms-client-principal-idp: "aad",
x-ms-client-principal-name: "me@example.com",
..
```

So that I have access to those headers from the Azure Function App (point of view).

### Questions

1. What exactly is the above-mentioned `authorization (bearer)` token for?
2. Is the above-mentioned `authorization (bearer)` token a "delegated token"? Which would then be usable as the valid token of the "signed-in user" so that I'd be able to make "delegated" calls to Microsoft Graph. Such as calling `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`
3. If the q.2 answer is no, then which of those above-mentioned user tokens/principles (forwarded by AAD) can be used to make "delegated" calls to Microsoft Graph?
4. If NONE of those AAD forwarded user tokens/principles can be used for "delegated" calls, does it mean that, the ONLY (ONLY) way to call Microsoft Graph API from the Azure Function is by "application permissions" approach?

Appreciate the helps on my confusions.

Comment: Could you include the scope while generating the token or while decoding the token?

Comment: To answer 1 and 2, you can decode the token at https://jwt.ms and check the token contents. `aud` will let you know what API the token is for. If the token contains a `scp` claim, then it is delegated and could be exchanged for other tokens with on-behalf-of flow.

Comment: Hi @juunas the `aud` only indicates the id (69418975-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX) of the AAD AppReg the SPFx is calling to. Did you mean that there is really a way to obtain "delegated" token that can be further used by "application"? Could you kindly share me some docs on how to obtain `scp` claims via SPFx please? Thank you so much.

Comment: Hmm.. If there is no scp claim, it might be an ID token instead of an access token. I think you can't exchange that one. I don't know anything about Share Point though :/

Comment: Dear @juunas could you advise on how to configure the AAD App so that it provides "access token" instead of "id token" as you mentioned please?

Answer (score 2):

> **Note** that: The Bearer token can be used to call Microsoft Graph API if  the token contains **`aud`** as Graph.

I agree with *juunas*, that the token you are passing is ID token and cannot be used to call API.

To call Microsoft Graph API, you need to retrieve the access token generated and check if the `aud` and `scp` value.

For sample I generated the access token and when decoded it the `aud` and `scp`  value is like below:

[image]

By using the access token, **I am able to get the signed-in user details successfully** like below:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

[image]

To make delegated calls to Microsoft Graph API, make sure to retrieve access token and try.

**References:**

[SPFx: Calling Microsoft Graph API from an AAD secured Azure Function on behalf of a user by Vardhaman Deshpande](https://www.vrdmn.com/2018/05/spfx-calling-microsoft-graph-api-from.html)